# Re-rendering a view in backbone Marionette: best practice

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

This is a very simple question.

Basically this is my case:

```
var newViewInstance1 = new MyView();
myLayout.myRegion.show(newViewInstance1)
```

Now, later, I want to show the View (which is a static one) again in the same layout region . There may or may not have been a different view in that region in the meantime.

Is there any difference between these two:

```
myLayout.myRegion.show(newViewInstance1) //again

//or
var newViewInstance2 = new MyView();
myLayout.myRegion.show(newViewInstance2)
```

If I do the latter, for example, will newViewInstance1 be left hanging around?

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real difference beyond the view initalization (e.g. if you're fetching or computing information in the view's `initialize` function).

In any case, when a region shows a view, it closes any open views in that region. So, no: `newViewInstance1` won't be left hanging around in the second case.